# conditional distribution regarding f(x,y,z)

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

Given that $$f(x,y,z) \propto x^2yz(1-2x-y-z),\mbox{ for }x>0,y>0,z>0, 2x+y+z < 1. $$

Find the conditional distribution of $X\mid  Y,Z$.

So how I have approached this qns is by using the formula $X\mid  Y,Z=  \frac {f(x,y,z)}{f(y,z)}$. However when I try to get the denominator by $\int_0^\infty f(x,y,z) dx $ , my expression goes to infinity and I'm stuck at this point

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Find the correct integral upper limit. If x goes to infinite, how about $2x+y+z < 1$

Comment: @a_statistician would the range of the integral be 0<x<0.5 ? Also since it is a proportional sign, do I have to find the normalizing constant of f(x,y,z) ?

Comment: if you do $\int_0 [\int_0[\int_0 f(x,y,z)dz] dy] dx $, i.e., integral $x$ last, 0.5 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x,y,z) =\begin{cases} x^2yz(1-2x-y-z) & \text{,for } x>0, y>0, z>0, 2x+y+z<1 \\0 & \text{,Otherwise}\end{cases}$.

We have $$f(x,y,z) = kg(x,y,z)$$ where $k$ is a constant and if $y,z \ge 0$ and $y+z\le 1$, $$f(y,z) = \int_0^\frac{1-y-z}2 kg(x,y,z) \, dx= k\int_0^\frac{1-y-z}2g(x,y,z) \, dx.$$

Hence $$\frac{f(x,y,z)}{f(y,z)}=\frac{kg(x,y,z)}{k\int_0^\frac{1-y-z}2g(x,y,z) \, dx}=\frac{g(x,y,z)}{\int_0^\frac{1-y-z}2g(x,y,z) \, dx}.$$

Hence there is no need to find the proportional constant.

Comment: $\int_0^\frac{1}2g(x,y,z) \, dz$ or $\int_0^\frac{1}2g(x,y,z) \, dx$?

Comment: Are you sure that  integral upper limit is 0.5?